# Replacing text in Grunt Template String

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

In my Grunt configuration, I have a template string link

```
"<%= gitinfo.local.branch.current.name %>"
```

which can contain text like "feature/feature1". How do I convert that to "feature-feature1"?

I tried using

```
"<%= gitinfo.local.branch.current.name %>".replace("/", "-")
```

but it looks like the replace call is happening before the text is substituted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

grunt uses [lodash templates](http://lodash.com/docs#template) where you can just use javascript:

```
"<%= gitinfo.local.branch.current.name.replace('/', '-') %>"
```